# Menu buttons not aligning in Edge browser

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, microsoft-edge

The page in question is here: http://dev.psdrotoworx.com/

When viewed in Edge, the menu buttons are rendering wider than they should. This causes the buttons to wrap into a new row, which is undesired behaviour. Like so:

[image: Edge incorrect rendering screenshot]

This issue is only appearing on the Edge browser, all other modern browsers are rendering as expected, which is like so:

[image: IE11 correct rendering screenshot]

Is anyone able to see where I am going wrong?

Can anyone explain why IE & Edge handles this differently?

Answer (score 1):

I did not get deep into your code but I think adding this:

```
width: 100px;
```

To your **.main-navigation .primary-menu > li** class in the **style.css** file might do the trick (somewhere around line *2975*).

Having fixed size here is not a big issue as I guess the menu do not have to respond to browser size changes.